# Como utilizar dois checkbox em uma view C# mvc para escolher o tipo de consulta?

Tags: c#, asp.net, query, mvc, checkbox

```html
Controller.cs

   public ActionResult pesquisarCliente(string _codigo)
        {
            var r = db.Pedido.AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_codigo))
            {
                r = r.Where(n => n.Cliente.Contains(_codigo));
                r.OrderBy(n => n.Cliente);
            }

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_Pedido",r.ToList());
            }

            return View(r.ToList());        
          
        }


_Pedito.cshtml - > PartialView

@model IEnumerable<DiskCaçamba.Pedido>


<div id="divlistapedido">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Data)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cliente)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EnderecoEntrega)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cacamba1.Descricao)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Loja1.NomeLoja)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Motorista1.NomeMotorista)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Situacao.Descricao)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cliente)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnderecoEntrega)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cacamba1.Descricao)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Loja1.NomeLoja)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Motorista1.NomeMotorista)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Situacao.Descricao)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.IdPedido }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.IdPedido }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.IdPedido })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>


View PesquisarCliente

@model IEnumerable<DiskCaçamba.Pedido>
<br />

<p>
    Pesquisar codigo
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("pesquisarCliente", "Consulta", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divlistapedido" }))
    {
        @Html.CheckBox("CbEndereço")   // Preciso especificar por endereço ou cliente
        @Html.Label("Endereço")

        <br />
        @Html.CheckBox("CbCodigo")
        @Html.Label("Codigo")

        <br />

                @Html.TextBox("_codigo")
                <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" />


                }
    </p>


<br />

    @Html.Partial("_Pedido", Model)


@Session Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")



}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso fazer a consulta por codigo ou endereço de acordo com a escolha do cliente.
Alguem tem alguma solução pra isso ?

Answer (score 0):

Na minha opinião, a melhor forma de se fazer uma pesquisa é utilizando o DataTable. Além dele já possuir uma caixa de pesquisa onde você pesquisa por todas as colunas, você pode configurar e criar caixas para pesquisar colunas distintas.

Aqui tem a documentação e um ótimo exemplo pra isso: https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html

DataTable facilita a vida de muitos programadores, sempre que eu preciso eu utilizo.

Answer (score 0):

Como você precisa pesquisar por código **OU** endereço, você precisará usar RadioBox ou ComboBox:

**RadioBox**

```
Codigo:   @Html.RadioButton("Pesquisa","Codigo")  
Endereco: @Html.RadioButton("Pesquisa","Endereco")
```

**ComboBox**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Pesquisa")
```